# PIG Dice game compiles and runs perfectly, but variables not changing from if statement. Suggestions?

Tags: java

```
package baker;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class PIG {
    final static int WINNING_SCORE = 100;
    final static int COMPUTER_THRESHOLD = 20;
    final static int NUM_SIDES = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int turnScore = 0;
        int turnScoreIf1 = 0;
        int computerScore = 0; 
        int humanScore = 0;
        int diceRoll;
        boolean turnContinues = true;
        String answer;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        while ((humanScore < WINNING_SCORE) && (computerScore < WINNING_SCORE)) {
            System.out.println("Your turn");
                while (turnContinues) 
                {

                System.out.print("Type r to Roll, or h to Hold ");
                    answer = keyboard.next();
                    if (answer.equals("r")) 
                    {
                        diceRoll = generator.nextInt(NUM_SIDES) + 1;
                            System.out.println("You rolled a " + diceRoll + "\n");  

                        if (diceRoll == 1) 

                        {
                            turnScore = 0;
                            System.out.println("Your total score is " + humanScore + ", ending turn" + "\n"); 
                            break;
                        }

                            else {
                                    humanScore = humanScore + diceRoll;
                                    turnScore = turnScore + diceRoll; 
                                    System.out.println("Your Turn Score:  " + turnScore);
                                    System.out.println("Your Total Score: " + humanScore +"\n");
                           if (humanScore >= 100)  
                           {
                                    System.out.println("You Win!" + "\n");
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    else if (answer.equals("h")) {
                                System.out.println("You chose to hold");
                                System.out.println("Your total score is " + humanScore); 

                    if (humanScore >= 100) 
                    { 
                                System.out.println("You win!");
                                return;
                    }

                                System.out.println("");
                                break;
                    }
                }
                turnScore = 0;
                System.out.println("Computer's Turn" + "\n");
                    while (turnContinues)
                        if (turnScore >= COMPUTER_THRESHOLD) {
                            System.out.println("Computer chose to hold.");
                            System.out.println("Computer's total score is " + computerScore + "\n"); 

                        if (computerScore >= 100) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("The computer wins!" + "\n");
                            return;

                        }
                        break;
                        }
                        else {
                            diceRoll = generator.nextInt(NUM_SIDES) + 1;
                            System.out.println("The computer rolled " + diceRoll);

                            if (diceRoll == 1) 
                            {
                                System.out.println("Computer's total score is " + computerScore + ", ending turn" + "\n");
                                break;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                computerScore = computerScore + diceRoll;
                                turnScore = turnScore + diceRoll; 

                                System.out.println("Computer turn score: " + turnScore); 
                                System.out.println("Computer total score: " + computerScore +"\n");

                                if (computerScore >= 100)  {
                                System.out.println("The Computer Wins!" + "\n");
                                return; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                turnScore = 0;
            }
        }           
    }
```

Like I said, the code runs fine, up until the code must reset for diceRoll == 1;. for whatever reason, the variable just doesn't change. As a matter of fact, the line forces the "assigned variable is never used. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: oh, and the variable turnScoreIf1 was a mistake, just disregard that in the declaration/initialization line.

Comment: When you say, "the variable doesn't change", which one? You have some cyclomatic complexity going on here, so you have to be more specific than "the variable", and mentioning "diceRoll==1" when there are multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear on the issue, but I added a method to reset the scores, calling it whenever there's a win condition. Is this what you mean by "the variable doesn't change"?

```
package baker;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class PIG {
    final static int WINNING_SCORE = 100;
    final static int COMPUTER_THRESHOLD = 20;
    final static int NUM_SIDES = 6;

    //moved these out of main so we can use a method to reset
    static int turnScore = 0;
    static int computerScore = 0; 
    static int humanScore = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int diceRoll;
        boolean turnContinues = true;
        String answer;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        while ((humanScore < WINNING_SCORE) && (computerScore < WINNING_SCORE)) {
            System.out.println("Your turn");
            while (turnContinues) 
            {

                System.out.print("Type r to Roll, or h to Hold ");
                answer = keyboard.next();
                if (answer.equals("r")) 
                {
                    diceRoll = generator.nextInt(NUM_SIDES) + 1;
                    System.out.println("You rolled a " + diceRoll + "\n");  

                    if (diceRoll == 1) 

                    {
                        turnScore = 0;
                        System.out.println("Your total score is " + humanScore + ", ending turn" + "\n"); 
                        break;
                    }

                    else {
                        humanScore = humanScore + diceRoll;
                        turnScore = turnScore + diceRoll; 
                        System.out.println("Your Turn Score:  " + turnScore);
                        System.out.println("Your Total Score: " + humanScore +"\n");
                        if (humanScore >= 100)  
                        {
                            System.out.println("You Win!" + "\n");
                            resetScores();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }


                else if (answer.equals("h")) {
                    System.out.println("You chose to hold");
                    System.out.println("Your total score is " + humanScore); 

                    if (humanScore >= 100) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println("You win!");
                        resetScores();
                        return;
                    }

                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                }
            }
            turnScore = 0;
            System.out.println("Computer's Turn" + "\n");
            while (turnContinues)
                if (turnScore >= COMPUTER_THRESHOLD) {
                    System.out.println("Computer chose to hold.");
                    System.out.println("Computer's total score is " + computerScore + "\n"); 

                    if (computerScore >= 100) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("The computer wins!" + "\n");
                        resetScores();
                        return;

                    }
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    diceRoll = generator.nextInt(NUM_SIDES) + 1;
                    System.out.println("The computer rolled " + diceRoll);

                    if (diceRoll == 1) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer's total score is " + computerScore + ", ending turn" + "\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        computerScore = computerScore + diceRoll;
                        turnScore = turnScore + diceRoll; 

                        System.out.println("Computer turn score: " + turnScore); 
                        System.out.println("Computer total score: " + computerScore +"\n");

                        if (computerScore >= 100)  {
                            System.out.println("The Computer Wins!" + "\n");
                            resetScores();
                            return; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            turnScore = 0;
        }
    }          

    public static void resetScores() {
        turnScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0; 
        humanScore = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Close, the rules of PIG say that if the player (or computer, if its on the computer turn) rolls a won, then their respective score for that turn is now zero, and the turn also ends. Below if (diceRoll == 1) I have the variable being turnScore being set to zero to address this rule. However it doesn't seem to work.